# Can't find window cod black ops

Tags: c++

So the problem I have is the C++ can't find cod black ops window. I don't know why. I think I typed everything right.
Here's the code its not the entire code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int ammop = 30;
int ammos = 30;




HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL, "Call of Duty®: BlackOps", 0);


if (hwnd == NULL){
    cout << "Cannot find window." << endl;
    Sleep(3000);
    exit(-1);
}
    else{
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

        if(procID == NULL){
             cout << "Cannot find window." << endl;
             Sleep(3000);
             exit(-1);
```

Comment: Does the code you show even compile? Without errors *or* warnings? I wonder because you call the wide-character function `FindWindowW` but pass a *narrow* character string as the window name. You also pass an extra zero not in the function specification (see e.g. [this `FindWindow` MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Also, you should probably check *what* the problem is if the function fails. Like using [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a possible error code.

Comment: The programs does not spit any erros just cant find the window its weird

Comment: "Does not spit any errors" is not the same as "Does not provide any information via `GetLastError`". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Just curios, what is a "window cod black ops" ?

Comment: It cat find a Call of Duty game window and now the program says HWND is not declared in this scope.

Comment: Just for a fun experiment, try prefixing the window name with an `L`, to make it a wide-character string. Just to see what happens. I.e. do `L"Call of Duty®: BlackOps"`. And drop that last argument (since there should not be any).

Comment: Do you mean `HWND`, `hWnd` or `hwnd`? Are you really sure you have build the exact code you show us? Is that really a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL, "Call of Duty®: BlackOps", 0);`

This shouldn't even compile.

1) FindWindow only takes 2 arguments

2) You're calling the wide char version of the function which is what the 'W' means, but you're passing a regular char pointer.

3) When you call GetWindowThreadProcessId you're passing `hwnd` which is not the correct var, C++ is case sensitive, you must use `hWnd` which is how you declared it

The correct code is:

`HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Call of Duty®: BlackOps");`

and

`GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &procID);`